# How to add third part libraries when developing smart contracts in EOS?

Tags: smart-contract, library

For example, if I want to add a random digital generator library, what can I do? I want to add all the source files into my contract directory?

Comment: You would have to add the whole library (or a reduced one) to your contract.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this,you are required to move your entire library to your contract. What you are attempting is not possible without this.